# Python: Formatting decimal passed to indexed position in format string

Tags: python, formatting, string-formatting, decimalformat

I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
>>> s = "Percent growth"
>>> decimal_value = 10.0123456789
>>> print("{0}: {1}".format(s, decimal_value)
Percent growth: 10.01
```

Specifically: how does one format decimal_value and pass it to {1}?  I am aware there are ways to do this using the old % operator.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for `str.format`? It links to the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) page, which explains what you're looking for and more.

Comment: Real programmers never read [documentation](http://docs.python.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.2f`  replacing the oldformat

```
print "{0}: {1:.2f}".format(s, decimal_value)
#output Percent growth: 10.01
```

Comment: What's a _try this_ answer?  Are you short of words to explain how you accomplished the desired?

Comment: Ah, smh, I saw something like {0:.2f} while searching and didn't make the connection that that "0" was indexing the position.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Schemer sometiomes happens;)